# How do you add text to a node frame?

Tags: node-editor

I have found the Frame in node layout. This is great but the Text field in the node doesn't seem to work. This probably means I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I am using Blender 3.1.

When I type text in to the TEXT field, it throws an error message. So how do I get text into that field? Or a comment block into a frame at all?

The online manual says "This is read-only, so you will need to use the Text Editor to modify the contents." but I thought this meant the type in box directly on the field. But that doesn't work. (notice the error message at the bottom of this image)

[image]

Comment: You can also add a short amount of text in the "Label:" input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the text editor to make a text then select the text in your node editor

Comment: Where is the text editor?

Comment: ARG!!!! Ok, I found it... THANKS! SHIFT+F11